# SetTimeout Not Working In Ember Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

```
setTimeout(function(){
Ember.$("#right-bar").addClass("col-lg-12");
Ember.$("#right-bar").removeClass("col-lg-2");
this.set('isExpanded',true);}, 250);
//this.set('isExpanded',true);
```

I'm trying to update the `isExpanded` value after a 250ms delay, but when I throw the commented line of code into a `setTimeout` function block (whether grouped or separately) it doesn't seem to update the value.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of scope, and you should probably Ember.run.later.  Additionally using `bind-attr` will make your life easier instead of manually changing the css.

```
var self = this;
Em.run.later(function(){
  Ember.$("#right-bar").addClass("col-lg-12");
  Ember.$("#right-bar").removeClass("col-lg-2");
  self.set('isExpanded',true);
}, 250);
```

or

```
Em.run.later(this, function(){
  Ember.$("#right-bar").addClass("col-lg-12");
  Ember.$("#right-bar").removeClass("col-lg-2");
  this.set('isExpanded',true);
}, 250);
```